# convertion from zipped object to list doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Despite making convertion to list, I am getting zipped object

```
import itertools as it
def combi(i,j):
    string_maps = {"1": "abc","2": "def","3": "ghi","4": "jkl","5": "mno","6": "pqrs","7": "tuv","8": "wxy","9": "z"}
    string_maps=dict((int(k),v) for k,v in string_maps.items())
    list1=[]
    list1.append(string_maps.get(i))
    list2=[]
    list2.append(string_maps.get(j))
    list_new =list([zip(x,list2) for x in it.permutations(list1,len(list2))])
    print(list_new)

combi(4,3)
```

Comment: `[zip(x,list2) for x in ...]` is a list of `zip` objects. What you're converting to list is the list this list comprehension produces

Comment: Should I get rid of list() conversion then? I am getting zipped object again

Comment: well, you don't need to, but it's redundant because `[...]` is already a list. What you want to do, however, is convert _each_ `zip` object to a list. You can do that with `list(zip(...))`, for example

Comment: thanks! Then, I messed up with nested list.